# Share Media Library Wordpress Multi Site Single Specific Folder

Tags: wordpress

We have a Wordpress Multisite setup for a group of travel agents.

Each agent gets to customize their own site.

We are looking for a way to share a group of stock images among all users of multisite. for example everyone would have access to `//wp-content/uploads/stock-images`

This folder would be pre approved travel related stock photo's that the agents are allowed to use in addition to any images they upload themselves to their own media library.

I have looked at two plugins "Add from Server" and "Network Shared Media".

Add from server is close but it allows the user to traverse through a bunch of directories when I want them to just be locked into one directory `//wp-content/uploads/stock-images`

Network Shared Media is also close but shares media from all network sites not just one folder

Does anyone know how to configure the above plugins to lock them down to `//wp-content/uploads/stock-images` or a plugin that would meet the above requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Scott